# Is it possible to get sharing stats for each checkin using the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

While reviewing the foursquare API documentation, I noticed that we can get stats on the number of checkins that were shared on Twitter and Facebook during a certain time period, thanks to the [Venue Stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats) for our venue.

We'd like to get that information for each checkin, however. Is this currently possible with the API? The [checkin object](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin) doesn't seem to include that information, but I might be looking at the wrong place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare doesn't support retrieving that information at the single check-in level (neither in the merchant console, nor the API).